# How to add rows to a merged Word table?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

This is how the table looks like.

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub WordTableTester()
Dim CurrentTable As table
Dim wdDoc As Document
Dim Rw As Long, col As Long
Dim wdFileName

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , "Please choose a file containing requirements to be imported")
If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    Set CurrentTable = wdDoc.Tables(1)
    Rw = 9: col = CurrentTable.Columns.Count
    wdDoc.Range(CurrentTable.Cell(Rw, 1).Range.start, _
    CurrentTable.Cell(Rw, col).Range.start).Select
    wdDoc.Application.Selection.InsertRowsBelow
End With


End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the an error message:  `Run-Time error '5941': The requested member of the collection does not exist.`

**Note:** I'm running a VBA Excel Macro and importing/adding rows to a table in a Word Doc

Comment: Have you tried looking at the code generated after doing it manually with the Macro Recorder running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with merged rows in MS Word Table is slightly tricky.

Is this what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim CurrentTable As Table
    Dim wdDoc As Document
    Dim Rw As Long, col As Long

    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument '<~~ Created this for testing
    Set CurrentTable = wdDoc.Tables(1)

    Rw = 9: col = CurrentTable.Columns.Count

    wdDoc.Range(CurrentTable.Cell(Rw, 1).Range.Start, _
    CurrentTable.Cell(Rw, col).Range.Start).Select

    wdDoc.Application.Selection.InsertRowsBelow
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**
[image]

**Edit**

You table's format is all screwed up. Table was created with few rows and then the cells were merged/split to create new rows and hence you were getting the error. Also since you are automating word from excel, I would recommend the following way.

Try this

```
Sub WordTableTester()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object, CurrentTable As Object
    Dim flName As Variant
    Dim Rw As Long, col As Long

    flName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", _
    , "Please choose a file containing requirements to be imported")

    If flName = False Then Exit Sub

    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(flName)
    Set CurrentTable = oWordDoc.Tables(1)

    Rw = 7: col = CurrentTable.Columns.Count

    oWordDoc.Range(CurrentTable.Cell(Rw, 1).Range.Start, _
    CurrentTable.Cell(Rw, col).Range.Start).Select

    oWordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertRowsBelow
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Also I couldn't get your code to work.

The `Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument` part is confusing me. Can you rewrite part of your code in incorporate `wdFileName`, `Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)`, and `With wdDoc` ? That'd be so great!!! I appreciate it so much :) **thanks**

Comment: Just ignore that line :) I used it for testing. You already have it initialzed in your code `Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)`

Comment: I can re-write but i want you to understand the code and try it yourself. If you are stuck then update your question with the code that you tried and then we will take it from there :)

Comment: I keep getting a "The requested member of the collection does not exist" error, and I'm not sure why or how to fix it. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/8nuzVcV.png) and [Code](https://pastebin.com/fUFgyNYn)

EDIT: I'll update the question with the code!! Sorry I just can't figure this one out! :(

Comment: Can I see your word file? If yes then can you upload it on a free file sharing site and share the link here

Comment: oh wait.. you are running this from Excel ... so change `Dim CurrentTable As Table` to `Dim CurrentTable As Object` and `Dim wdDoc As Document` to `Dim wdDoc As Object`

Comment: Yup!! Here: [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B21kfYOWvuBmdXN5NG5qNURIcnM)

Comment: Yup I am running this from excel. I just changed the variable types but I am still running into that same "Requested member doesn't exist" error

Comment: Ok there is a problem with this table.... You want to insert row after which row? Do not give me the number but give me the contents of the first and second cell

Comment: Insert after the "Option Units Conditions" row. Like this: [Image Link](http://i.imgur.com/mpeh3lx.png)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! :))))) Let me know if you need anything in return! I'd love to help give back - I've been stuck on this problem for days. Thanks again so much Siddharth!!! (IT works!)
@Siddharth

Comment: No I do not need anything :) Glad it worked for you :)